# INSERT INTO copying from table to another

Tags: mysql

I have a table with `lang_name` and `country_name` columns.

In this table I have a listing of the countries like:

```
English   ANDORRA
English   UNITED ARAB EMIRATES
English   AFGHANISTAN
```

I need to format this on a `country_names` table

```
id English Spanish French Italian
1  BRAZIL  BRAZIL  BRÉSIL  BRASILE
```

I tried to use something like this and this works aonly for one language

```
INSERT INTO co_names (English)
SELECT country_name
FROM ulkeler
WHERE lang_name = 'English'
```

When I change to

```
INSERT INTO co_names (Spanish)
SELECT country_name
FROM ulkeler
WHERE lang_name = 'Spanish'
```

It says worked but when I checked I don't see any record in Spanish part.

My table creation is like this

```
CREATE TABLE `co_names` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `English` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `Spanish` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `French` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `German` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `Italian` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `Portugues` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `Turkish` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

You can see my ulkeler db as csv here. [http://www.mytiq.net/multilanugage country.csv](http://www.mytiq.net/multilanugage%20country.csv)

Comment: Neither `INSERT` will work because the other columns have `NOT NULL` constraints.

Comment: so i must change to DEFAULT NULL?

Comment: I don't think so. But we need another column on the `ulkeler` table in order to link the countries together e.g. `country_id`. Is there one?

Comment: Sorry ı found that ı have a kind of country id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO co_names 
(
id, English, Spanish, French, German, Italian, Portugues, Turkish
)
SELECT CONVERT(country_numeric_code, UNSIGNED), 
IFNULL((SELECT MAX(country_name) FROM ulkeler WHERE u.lang_name = 'ENGLISH'), 'Unknown'),
IFNULL((SELECT MAX(country_name) FROM ulkeler WHERE u.lang_name = 'SPANISH'), 'Unknown'),
IFNULL((SELECT MAX(country_name) FROM ulkeler WHERE u.lang_name = 'FRENCH'), 'Unknown'),
IFNULL((SELECT MAX(country_name) FROM ulkeler WHERE u.lang_name = 'GERMAN'), 'Unknown'),
IFNULL((SELECT MAX(country_name) FROM ulkeler WHERE u.lang_name = 'ITALIAN'), 'Unknown'),
IFNULL((SELECT MAX(country_name) FROM ulkeler WHERE u.lang_name = 'PORTUGUESE'), 'Unknown'),
IFNULL((SELECT MAX(country_name) FROM ulkeler WHERE u.lang_name = 'TURKISH'), 'Unknown')
FROM ulkeler u
GROUP BY country_numeric_code;
```

Note misspelling of the 'Portuguese' column (missing last 'e') in your `co_names` table.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the original data structure, because you have no way of tying the rows together.  So, you have one row that is "ENglish, 'United States'" another that is "French, "Etats-Unis"' and another that is "Spanish, "Estados Unidos".  How do you know that these are the same country?

If you have a country identifier, the query you want is pretty easy:

```
select countryId,
       max(case when lang_name = 'Englist' then co_name end) as English,
       max(case when lang_name = 'French' then co_name end) as French,
      . . .
from ulkeler
group by countryId
```

I fear that you are going to say something like "well, they are inserted into the table in the same order for each language."  That's nice.  But SQL tables are inherently unordered.  So, you cannot use the ordering.

If I were faced with this data, I would probably import the data into Excel, rearrange the columns there, and re-import into the database.  Another option would be to import the data into a table that has an auto-increment option.  Then you might have the information you need to line up the rows.

Comment: ı have the country numeric code and the countries allways are in the same order

Comment: İmporting to excel; i can do that only for couple of languages but my aim is for more than ten languages

Answer (score 0):

is there any message like '0 rows inserted.' after you inserted it? run SQL query `SELECT country_name FROM ulkeler WHERE lang_name = 'Spanish'` for checking result of select query. maybe its because `lang_name = 'Spanish'` has no result. if it is happened then you just `insert new record` which has 'Spanish' in lang_name column in `ulkeler` table.

Comment: When i run spanish after english it write to to rows after english. i need to se tha next to english

Comment: so in your ulkuler table, there are data like this:
English   ANDORRA
English   UNITED ARAB EMIRATES
English   AFGHANISTAN
Spanish   ANDORRAinSpanish
Spanish   UNITED ARAB EMIRATESinSpanish
Spanish   AFGHANISTANinSpanish
then you want to make it like:
English     | Spanish
ANDORRA       ANDORRAinSpanish
AFGHANISTAN   AFGHANISTANinSpanish
??? if it is true, then i think you need to rebuild your ulkuler table first, cause it will make confused, we wont know which one is match to another

Comment: english United arab emirates spanish Emiratos arabes unidos an di have country number codes